# How to put pie charts on a SVG map?

Tags: javascript, svg, charts, maps, amcharts

I use such a map on my website, it's created by amCharts:

[image]

All regions are SVG path elements. I'm thinking how to put a chart.js (or any other) pie chart on each of them. The chart of chart.js is a canvas element. Is there any easy solution to achieve it? I could also change the map provider if neccessary.

This should be the effect:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [demo](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/map-dynamic-pie-charts/) on the AmCharts website that shows how to do that. You essentially need to create image markers that you can place on your map using latitude and longitude coordinates and use the `positionChanged` event to create/update custom external divs which contain your pie charts.

Comment: Thank you, I completely missed it! However, when I apply the whole solution that is suggested and coded in an example I get the message: 'd.AmPieChart is not a constructor'. I wonder what might be wrong this time.

Comment: Ok, I need to link also to the amchart library now ;).

Comment: Yep - you need to include the chart library as well. Also note that in the example you have to use `ammap_amcharts_extension.js` instead of `ammap.js` in order to use both charts and maps on the same page without the libraries clashing. Just want to call that out since that's a common oversight